# ScrollView not updated with imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have 20 images in my main bundle and i want to display it in my scroll view horizontally.

I am doing it successfully but now the problem is images are visible in scrollview after all imageview are set in scroll view and it takes time.

For resolve that I create one nsoperation.

```
-(BOOL)sync:(NSError**)error
{
    float imageLeftPosition = 0;

    for (int imageCount = 1; imageCount<=syncObject.syncNumberOfImages; imageCount++) {

        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageLeftPosition, 0, syncObject.syncImageWidth, syncObject.syncImageHeight)];

        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d.jpg",syncObject.syncChapterNumber,imageCount]]];

        imgView.tag = imageCount;

//        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary new];
//        
//        [dictionary setValue:imgView forKey:CHAPTER_IMAGE];

        imageLeftPosition = imageLeftPosition+syncObject.syncImageWidth;

        //[dictionary setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",imageLeftPosition] forKey:CHAPTER_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION];

      NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:imgView,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",imageLeftPosition], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:CHAPTER_IMAGE,CHAPTER_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION, nil]];

        [self sendNotification:dictionary];

        imgView = nil;
        dictionary = nil;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

what i am doing here is add create one image view and post it to main view using notification

```
-(void)addImageView:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSInteger thread = [NSThread isMainThread]?CVC_MainThread:CVC_BackgroundThread;
    switch (thread) {
        case CVC_MainThread:
        {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = notification.userInfo;
            if(dictionary != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"image view : %@",(UIImageView*)[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_IMAGE]);
                 NSLog(@"leftposition: %f",[[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION] floatValue]);
                [_scrChapters addSubview:((UIImageView*)[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_IMAGE])];
                _scrChapters.contentSize = CGSizeMake([[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION] floatValue], 0);
            }
            dictionary = nil;
        }
            break;

        case CVC_BackgroundThread:
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                NSDictionary *dictionary = notification.userInfo;
                if(dictionary != nil)
                {

                    NSLog(@"image view : %@",(UIImageView*)[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_IMAGE]);
                    NSLog(@"leftposition: %f",[[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION] floatValue]);
                    [_scrChapters addSubview:((UIImageView*)[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_IMAGE])];
                    _scrChapters.contentSize = CGSizeMake([[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION] floatValue], 0);

                }
                dictionary = nil;
            });
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

this is the notification handler method where i set the content size and image view in scroll view for each loop on main thread still scroll view are visible after all the images are load.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: is the content size is correct in this [[dictionary valueForKey:CHAPTER_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION] floatValue] cross check with a static value as image count* image size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pagedflowview. This will load only the visible items into the Scrollview and is easy to customize. You can also search for iCarousel.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagedflowview

Comment: yes that is one option but I want to know whta is the issue with current logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)showimagesasSlide:(int) totalimagesCount
{
    int xAxisofimageView=0;

    for (int initialimagesCount=0;initialimagesCount<totalimagesCount; initialimagesCount++) {
        UIImageView *detailedImageview=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        detailedImageview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        UIImage *dynamicImage=[ScaleImageSize squareImageWithImage:[images objectAtIndex:initialimagesCount] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500) ];


        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            detailedImageview.frame=CGRectMake(xAxisofimageView, 0, 320, 568);

        }
        else
        {
            detailedImageview.frame=CGRectMake(xAxisofimageView, 0, 320, 460);

        }
     //   detailedImageview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;


        detailedImageview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        detailedImageview.image=dynamicImage;
        detailedImageview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  ;
        detailedImageview.tag=initialimagesCount+12;

        [mainScrollview addSubview:detailedImageview];
        xAxisofimageView=xAxisofimageView+320;

      }
    mainScrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320*images.count, 0);
}
```